# VSIX Exstension: How to paste the text from clipboard to the environment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am developing a VSIX extension, which is aimed to make some string, copy it to clipboard and paste it to the current position of cursor in VS. For example, I am working with a code file, my cursor is on the 15th line. I call my extension and it pastes some generated string where my cursor is (15th line, as in the example).

The only thing I can't figure out is how to paste the string from the clipboard to the environment? I've already searched for tons of websites and still can't figure it out. Here is my function, that implements the functionality:

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
    todayDate = NecessaryFunctions.TodayDatefun();
    string projName = NecessaryFunctions.ProjectNamefun();
    string output = "// " + projName + ", " + todayDate;
    DTE dte;
    Clipboard.SetText(output);
    //= Clipboard.GetText(); - what should I do here to paste it to the environment?
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by environment? Usually, a paste operation is initiated by the user through either a menu item selection "Copy", or a keyboard shortcut (CRTL+V). 

If there is an active designer or editor in the VS IDE that has input focus, you could programmatically execute the Paste command, via the DTE.ExecuteCommand, or the IVsUIShell.PostExecCommand API.

Comment: I meant that how to paste my string from clipboard to the document automatically. I called it environment because the code document is opened in IDE :)

Comment: Why are you using the clipboard here versus just directly inserting the text?

Comment: So this was my question. How to insert the text directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code example

```
DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
TextSelection selectedText = (TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection; // gets all the selected text (if not, it gets the current cursor)
selectedText.Insert(Clipboard.GetText()); // pastes the text lol
```